Copying Locked/In-Use Files with NodeJS/Electron
I am creating a quick script where the goal is to copy files to another location.  The catch is that the script, primarily for Windows computers, will be locked/in-use by the operating system.  Therefore, using something like fs.CopyFileSync, unfortunately, errors with an EBUSY ("resource busy or locked") message.
Is there a method in NodeJS to get around this? I have tried (and failed) to find a package that can perform this, but am assuming I need to find a different method of copying and recreating the data, but don't really know where to start.  I know in Python this is as easy as using the shutil module, but am a little newer to Node.
